# Spring Boot Getting Started Content import not completing

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

On Spring Tool Suite 4.11.1 I did the following:

- File > New > Other > Spring Boot > Spring Starter Project
- Filled the data on the screen (group, artifact...) and clicked Next
- Left Spring Boot Version 2.5.4 selection
- Selected: Rest Repositories, Spring Data JPA, Spring Web
- Clicked Finish

Then it says "Import Getting Started Content (26%)" at the bottom right.

But it's been 1 hour and that percentage didn't change.

And if I check on Windows Explorer it is the same number of files from the begining (60).

I have done this process in the past and it takes just 5 minutes or so.

So it's clearly not working.

I don't get any error. It just stays at that percentage with the running green bar.

But it's not completing the process. Why is that?

Comment: restarting the STS app might work for you

Comment: have tried that already. Even restarted the notebook. This is the second time running. First time took 30min when I gave up and did the restart.

Comment: Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA could your options as well if you are really stuck on STS app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this.

On STS go to:
Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections > Chage from Native to Manual or Direct.

Did this and now it worked. Quickly completed the process.

Answer (score 0):

Analysis of facing issue with Spring Boot Getting Started Content import not completing

Below is the analysis

- Analysis 1 :- (Failed case)

Create Spring Starter project

select JAVA version 8

After that select dependency – 1. Spring Web 2. Spring Lombok

Its going to stuck

- Analysis 2 :-

- Create Spring Starter Project
- Select JAVA version 8
- After that select dependency -1.Spring Web 2.Spring Boot dev tool
- its going to work fine

- Analysis 3 :- ( Pass case)

- Create Spring Starter Project
- Select JAVA version 11
- After that select dependency -1.Spring Web 2.Spring Boot dev tool
- its going to work fine

- Analysis  4 : - ( Failed case )

- Create Spring Starter Project
- Select JAVA version 11
- After that select dependency – 1. Spring Web 2. Spring Lombok
- Its going to stuck

Issue because of Spring Lombok dependency